# Xamarin Forms Grid not placing label on top of image

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to place text over an image using a grid. However, it seems that Xamarin places the label above the image for some strange reason.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="profile_banner.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
  <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ProfileName, StringFormat='Welcome, {0}'}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" />
</Grid>
```

And here's a picture of what's happening: 
[image]

I'd like to get the text inside of the dark banner below it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this case `GridView` is not the right layout type to use.
You should use `RelativeLayout` instead. 
Here is a good example from [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17794/image-as-background#latest):

```
public static Page GetMainPage ()
{   
    var myLabel = new Label () {
        Text = "Hello World",
        Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize (20),
        TextColor = Color.White,
        XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
        YAlign = TextAlignment.Center
    };

    var myImage = new Image () {
        Source = FileImageSource.FromUri (
            new Uri("http://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/index/hero-slide.jpg"))
    };

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout ();

    layout.Children.Add (myImage, 
        Constraint.Constant (0), 
        Constraint.Constant (0),
        Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
        Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => { return parent.Height; }));

    layout.Children.Add (myLabel, 
        Constraint.Constant (0), 
        Constraint.Constant (0),
        Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => { return parent.Width; }),
        Constraint.RelativeToParent ((parent) => { return parent.Height; }));

    return new ContentPage { 
        Content = layout
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@EvZ I think Grid layout is correct...

You can try do

1- define also RowDefinition
2- set Grid.Row = "0" for Image and Label

Good Luck

Comment: Most probably it will work but if you need more flexibility I would choose RelativeLayout. It just doesn't make sense to have a Grid to draw a View on a top of another View.